# Android Navigation drawer toggle won't respond after upgrading from mvvmcross 6 to 7 and to androidx

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an mvvmcross application that uses MVVMcross 6.4.2 and implements drawer navigation using Fragment and activity presentation just as what we have in the [starwars sample on github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples).
This worked fine, untill I decided to migrate from MvvmCross 6.7.2 to 7.1.2
After this migration, I also migrated support packages to androidx packages, and changed the namespaces appropriately till the app could run.

Then, later I noticed the navigation drawer won't open anymore. the Drawer toggle button, was there and I could click it but the drawer was not opening. even sliding from the left didn't open the drawer. I did no modification to the navigation drawer that worked before migration all I did was update nugget packages and change to androidx namespaces when I got an error.

And the most annoying thing is that, I have no log in the output window which could give me a clue about the issue. I checked in my axml files if migration of namespaces where ok, and I deleted my MenuFragment, and started it back, copying and pasting what was in the starwars sample I mentioned earlier, but it still didn;t change a thing

I'm sure I might be missing something, can someone help ? please

Comment: Check the SplitDetail from the [Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Droid), also check the presentation attributes

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out